Resolution on Linux Mint 21.3 blurry and oversized, all display options greyed out
I just got a new computer the other day with Windows 11 Pro and, naturally, I added the newest Linux Mint to Dual Boot. I have an AMD Ryzen 5600G with integrated graphics.
The monitor and display works amazing in Windows, all is normal, but the scaling went awful and blurry when I first started the live of Linux from the installation USB.
I thought it would fix itself after the install, it didn't. I did an update, too, restarted, and no change.
This is what display settings look like:
Display settings in Linux Mint 21.3
and here's how blurry it all is
Linux Mint welcome screen all blurry
I don't have multiple monitors, I use a VGA cable and have an ASUS monitor that I'm not certain of the exact specs now, but it works amazing on my other Linux computer.

It seems you don't have installed/working AMD graphics drivers and you should because they're open source and should be enabled by default. I don't know Mint, other than it's Ubuntu based so it may share the same installer. Did you by any chance, NOT selected an option to install 3rd party drivers? Note: I shouldn't matter anyway but...

I actually can't remember seeing that option, there was only the multimedia codecs on the main installation. How do I go about doing that now?

As I said, I don't know Mint.
